# How to calculate Covariance and Correlation in Python without using cov and corr?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

How can we calculate the correlation and covariance between two variables without using *cov* and *corr* in Python3?
At the end, I want to write a function that returns three values:

1. a boolean that is true if two variables are independent
2. covariance of two variables
3. correlation of two variables.

You can find the definition of correlation and covariance here:

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/covariance-and-correlation-math-and-python-code-7cbef556baed

I wrote this part for covariance:
'''

```
ans=[]
    mean_x , mean_y = x.mean() , y.mean()
    n = len(x)
    Cov = sum((x - mean_x) * (y - mean_y)) / n
    sum_x = float(sum(x))
    sum_y = float(sum(y))
    sum_x_sq = sum(xi*xi for xi in x)
    sum_y_sq = sum(yi*yi for yi in y)
    psum = sum(xi*yi for xi, yi in zip(x, y))
   num = psum - (sum_x * sum_y/n)
   den = pow((sum_x_sq - pow(sum_x, 2) / n) * (sum_y_sq - pow(sum_y, 2) / n), 0.5)
   if den == 0: return 0
        return num / den
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

For the covariance, just subtract the respective means and multiply the vectors together (using the dot product). (Of course, make sure whether you're using the sample covariance or population covariance estimate -- if you have "enough" data the difference will be tiny, but you should still account for it if necessary.)

For the correlation, divide the covariance by the standard deviations of both.

As for whether or not two columns are independent, that's not quite as easy. For two random variables, we just have that $\mathbb{E}\left[(X - \mu_X)(Y - \mu_Y)\right] = 0$, where $\mu_X, \mu_Y$ are the means of the two variables. But, when you have a data set, you are not dealing with the actual probability distributions; you are dealing with a sample. That means that the correlation will very likely not be *exactly* $0$, but rather a value close to $0$. Whether or not this is "close enough" will depend on your sample size and what other assumptions you're willing to make.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But can you help me in writing the code?

Comment: I'll show you how you could have gotten the correlation without as much code:
`(x - x.mean())@(y - y.mean()) / x.std() / y.std() / n`.
You can do similar for covariance (just don't divide by the standard deviation).